# Java axis1.X client change address

Tags: java, ip-address, axis

I used axis1 tool to generate my client from a WSDL. My problem is that I want to connect to a different host than the one on the WSDL. As such I did:

```
new BobsledWSHostLocator("http://localhost:8731/Bobsled/Core/?wsdl", new QName("http://lint.com/schemas/Bobsled", "BobsledWSHost"));
```

But when I try to comunicate with the host it still goes to the address I have on the wsdl from which I generated the client...when it should go to localhost.

I wanted to change the host address diagrammatically so I can have various hosts.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
BobsledWSHostLocator locator = new BobsledWSHostLocator();
BobsledWSHostService service = locator.getBobsledWSHostHttpPort(new URL("http://localhost:8731/Bobsled/Core/?wsdl"));
```

Comment: I don't have a .getBobsledWSHostHttpPort...but I have for the other services...should I use it in each one? Isn't there a way to change all the ports at once?

Answer (score 0):

Axis should also have generated a class ending in `BindingStub`, which has a constructor taking the URL of the webservice endpoint and a `org.apache.axis.client.Service` object which can be constructed given the `QName` of your service. It might look something like this:

```
new BobsledWSHostBindingStub(
    new URL("http://example.com/Bobsled/Core/"),
    new Service(new QName("http://lint.com/schemas/Bobsled", "BobsledWSHost")));
```

**Edit:** That is actually the same code that the `get*Port` method that [nwinkler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1228454/nwinkler) mentioned uses internally.

Comment: Nope it didn't...only have BobsledWSHostLocator and BobsledWSHost (which is an Interface).
I don't get it...if BobsledWSHostLocator can receive wsdlocator why doesn't it change the service address to localhost?